# Is $(\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z)^\times\cong (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times\times(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $n$ any positive integer.

Is $(\mathbb Z/p^{n+1}\mathbb Z)^\times\cong (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times\times(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)$ as groups?

This seems very likely as the orders agree, but I'm unable to find an explicit isomorphism.

Is there one?

Thanks.

Comment: Only when $p$ is odd or $n$ is at most $1$. Because $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is not cyclic for $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Thanks- I've now corrected the wording of the question.

Comment: For the revised version the answer is yes. The reason is that both the groups mentioned are cyclic (the direct product by an easy argument, and the other one by a somewhat more involved one that I will leave to others to expand on in an answer, though I have a feeling it must have been asked before).

Comment: It's pretty easy to show (when $p$ is odd) that if $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_{p^n}^\times$ then either $g$ or $g+p$ is a generator for $\mathbb Z_{p^{n+1}}^\times$, so these groups are all cyclic.

Comment: There is a natural short exact sequence $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ where the first map is $x + (p^n) \mapsto 1+x\cdot p+(p^{n+1})$ and the second is reduction modulo $p$. If you want to find a split $\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ I think you will need a primitive root modulo $p^{n+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of $U(N) = (\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ for any positive integer $N$ is worked out in $\S$ 1.6 of [this prebook](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400FULL.pdf).  In particular the first theorem in that section affirmatively answers your question.

By the way, your assertion that "this seems very likely as the orders agree" does not seem like a good way of thinking about it to me.  First of all that assertion applies also to $p = 2$, in which case $U(2^a) \cong Z_2 \times Z_{2^{a-2}}$ is not cyclic for all $a \geq 3$.  (Although I suppose a family of statements parameterized by the primes and is true for all $p$ except $2$ is, in a quite reasonable sense, "very likely"!) For any prime $p$, the number of isomorphism classes of commutative groups of order $p^n$ is $P(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$.  Thus two randomly chosen groups of order $p^n$ are very probably not isomorphic.

Now the unit group of a finite ring $\mathfrak{r}$ is not a random finite commutative group.  Given what happens with $\mathbb{Z}/p^a\mathbb{Z}$, you might expect that when $\mathfrak{r}$ has prime power order it is more likely to be cyclic than a random group of its order.  As it happens I did some calculations about a month ago with a large class of unit groups of finite residue rings of Dedekind domains.  I was surprised by how rarely they came out to be cyclic!  This shows up in the proof of Theorem 17 [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/abstractqrNEW.pdf), which admittedly is the middle of something relatively technical.  A clearer glimpse at the phenomenon might be gained by consulting the short paper of C.S. Dalawat (available on the arxiv) cited therein.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link to your book. I've had a quick look at theorem 22 of section 1.6 and it sure implies that the two groups in my original question are isomorphic since they're both cyclic, although it doesn't give an explicit isomorphism between the two as I was hoping. Or maybe I just haven't read your book or your comments above carefully enough!

Comment: @Mark: You're right, I don't give an explicit isomorphism.  This is a hard problem!  The difficulty resides in the case of $a = 1$: a generator of $g$ of $U(p)$ is called a **primitive root modulo p** and there's a lot of literature on that.  If you have such a generator, then it's easy to find a generator for $U(p^a)$: see Thomas Andrews's comment above.

Comment: By the way, I missed the word "explicit" in your question.  If it's the explicitness that is of particular interest to you, then you should probably unaccept my answer, as there is a lot to say about finding primitive roots and almost none of it occurs in the linked prebook (there is a short discussion on p. 28, but it still focuses more on theoretical than algorithmic issues).